# How to connect to a remotely hosted Firebird database via SSH using PHP

Tags: php, ssh, firebird

I need to create a PHP script that connects via SSH tunnel to a remote host, connects to a Firebird database and access some data.
I've looked around and I managed to get the SSH connection and tunneling right, but I don't know how to properly connect to Firebird after that.

Here's the code I'm using now:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('hostname', 22);

if (!$connection)
    die('No connection...');
else
    echo 'Connection ok! ';

if (ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password'))
    echo "Authentication Successful! ";
else
    die('Authentication Failed...');

$sshTunnel = ssh2_tunnel($connection, '127.0.0.1', 3050);
if ($sshTunnel)
    echo "Tunnel created! ";
else
    die("Tunnel failed...");

if ($dbh = ibase_connect('127.0.0.1/3050:D:\path\to\db\database.fdb', 'username', 'password'))
{
    echo 'Connected to the database!';
}else{
    echo 'Connection failed...';
}
```

Everything is ok up to the tunneling. The error that PHP returns when I call ibase_connect is this:

> Warning: ibase_connect(): Unable to complete network request to host
>   "127.0.0.1". Failed to establish a connection.

I already tried doing everything using Putty/ssh.exe/telnet and encountered no problem whatsoever.
I know that mysqli_connect can do it like this:

```
mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'DB_USERNAME', 'DB_PASSWORD', 'dbname', port, $tunnel);
```

I didn't find any documentation about something similar using ibase_connect.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ssh2-tunnel.php - the last argument is integer not string. Your code in the question is not the real one you run

Comment: I do not see your tunnel ever opening Firebird's port (3050 by default), so it seems to go to nowhere. For example we may compare with zebedee/openvpn tunnels like http://www.ibase.ru/zebedee ( www.tranlsate.ru ) - there is always explicit specification of BOTH ports: inbound tunnel socket and outbound 3050 firebird socket, then local client connects to the inbound port

Comment: @Arioch'The, actually, it works even with the port parameter like that. Anyway, I tried passing an integer and the result is the same.

Comment: Apologies to everyone, I fixed the code posted here with the same ports I'm using right now, but the result is the same.

Comment: you need to somehow open that ssh tunnel to TCP stack of your local OS. Or use other tunnels that do. you connect your FB client to INBOUND host/port of the tunnel, and the OUTBOUND end of the tunnel connects to the FB server. Look pictures on Wikipedia! There are two connections. FB Client to INBOUND tunnel host/port and then OUTBOUND tunnel end to DB server host/port.  The php manuals `ssh2_tunnel($connection, '127.0.0.1', 3050);` sound as you set OUTBOUND end to FB Server at 127.0.0.1/3050 (if there is any) Now u have to find INBOUND end of tunnel and pass INBOUND h/p to `ibase_connect`

Comment: If there EXISTS the inbound end of tunnel. I am not sure PHP created it, just do not know.

Comment: `ssh2_tunnel` establishes a socket stream through ssh, and afaik the `ibase` methods in PHP doesn't support that. You might want to look at creating an SSH tunnel outside your PHP application, see https://www.engadget.com/2006/03/21/how-to-ssh-tunnels-for-secure-network-access/ for an example.